# Python Save A single Item loop for String List

Tags: string, list, for-loop, split, python-2.4

I'm new in python and I'm creating a **python 2.4 script** that contains these code lines:

```
   line1 = 67169   58898
   words = line1.split()
   for i in range(len(words)):
       print (words[1])
```

When executing the script I got this:

```
 58898
 58898
```

What I need is a variable that contains only one **58898**

Comment: if you want to get only last element for each line then you can do like this, `print words[-1] `, instead of looping each element.

Comment: it's the same result, i need just only 58898 the end of the second line in a variable that i can use it.

Comment: This is the solution that i found 
                **words = line1.split()**
                **for i in words[1:]:**
                    **print i**